# Android notification badge on launcher icon

Tags: android, notifications, chat, message, badge

I want to show unread messages count on my android app's launcher icon. It should be cleared only, once the user read all messages. I have tried setnumber method inside my firebase push notification service class. But it is not showing badge count. Then I used this library, https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger . Now it is showing badge count. But the problem is,when user open the app or remove notifications this badge count will automatically disappear. How can I show badge count on launcher icon?